# Can't load External Source to <use> tag of SVG

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I got an error that I really have no idea how to deal with it. This is error is: [From Cr]

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Users/Ho%20Thi%20Kim%20Loan/Desktop/BeTe/assets/file-text2.svg#icon-file-text2 from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Ho%20Thi%20Kim%20Loan/Desktop/BeTe/index.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

My code looks just like [CSS-Trick](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source),

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="assets/file-text2.svg#icon-file-text2"></use>
</svg>
```

My SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <symbol id="icon-file-text2" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
        <title>file-text2</title>
        <path class="path1" d="M917.806 229.076c-22.212-30.292-53.174-65.7-87.178-99.704s-69.412-64.964-99.704-87.178c-51.574-37.82-76.592-42.194-90.924-42.194h-496c-44.112 0-80 35.888-80 80v864c0 44.112 35.888 80 80 80h736c44.112 0 80-35.888 80-80v-624c0-14.332-4.372-39.35-42.194-90.924zM785.374 174.626c30.7 30.7 54.8 58.398 72.58 81.374h-153.954v-153.946c22.984 17.78 50.678 41.878 81.374 72.572zM896 944c0 8.672-7.328 16-16 16h-736c-8.672 0-16-7.328-16-16v-864c0-8.672 7.328-16 16-16 0 0 495.956-0.002 496 0v224c0 17.672 14.326 32 32 32h224v624z"></path>
        <path class="path2" d="M736 832h-448c-17.672 0-32-14.326-32-32s14.328-32 32-32h448c17.674 0 32 14.326 32 32s-14.326 32-32 32z"></path>
        <path class="path3" d="M736 704h-448c-17.672 0-32-14.326-32-32s14.328-32 32-32h448c17.674 0 32 14.326 32 32s-14.326 32-32 32z"></path>
        <path class="path4" d="M736 576h-448c-17.672 0-32-14.326-32-32s14.328-32 32-32h448c17.674 0 32 14.326 32 32s-14.326 32-32 32z"></path>
    </symbol>
</defs>
```

The SVG image upper is belong to [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io)

Now I really want to know how to deal with that error. All of my protocols and ports do match, and this is localhost. How on earth it could have a domain? (Don't you think it is a bug?)

Comment: Chrome considers local files to be external domain. And it's not considered as a bug. Other browsers don't have this behavior. You can deactivate this on Chrome by launching from command line/terminal and setting allow-file-access-from-files as argument. How to do it depends on your OS.

Comment: Thanks @JulienGrégoire but can you clarify the part 'setting allow-file-access-from-files as argument'. I'm not pretty sure how to do it. And Cr only consider on local files or any kind of host? I intend to make a Cr app... (I'm using Windows 8.1)

Comment: Hello mate - I was just wandering if you found work around to this problem. I get exactly same issue, following exact same advice from Chris Coyer :)

Comment: I am also getting the same issue @StarLight if you found a workaround to this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Julien comment this won't work locally (not in Chrome, Opera or IE, but is fine on Firefox), so you need to do whole this on server.

Also I figured out, that in my case (as in yours too), it was also a matter of removing `<defs></defs>` element from my external `svg` file, as it prevents its content from being displayed.

So go ahead and wipe it out, and all should work as expected.